# Configure default proxy address with Vite

Tags: reactjs, vite

I would like to configure a default path `"/"` for my proxy to hit my server.

this is my `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react-swc';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/": {
        // prependPath: true,
        target: "http://localhost:8080",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        rewrite: path => path.replace(/^\//, '')
        // ws: true,
      }
    }, 
  }
});
```

so that in my client, with I `fetch("/todos")` it reaches `http://localhost:8080/todos`. Both with or without rewrite, I'm not able to make it work. This fetch would currently only reach `http://localhost:8080`.

Similar to adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` in a create-react-app's `package.json`

Any ideas? Thank you